flexRender function not rendering content in table cells ( tanstack table and shadcn )
i want to build a table with react and shadcn, but i am not getting what i want: there is no content in table cell . this is my code:
import {
  ColumnDef,
  flexRender,
  getCoreRowModel,
  useReactTable,
} from "@tanstack/react-table";

import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableHeader,
  TableRow,
} from "@/components/ui/table";

interface DataTableProps<TData, TValue> {
  columns: ColumnDef<TData, TValue>[];
  data: TData[];
}

function Checks<TData, TValue>({
  columns,
  data,
}: DataTableProps<TData, TValue>) {
  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
  });
  return (
    <div className="rounded-md border">
      <Table>
        <TableHeader>
          {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
            <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
                return (
                  <TableHead key={header.id}>
                    {flexRender(
                      header.column.columnDef.header,
                      header.getContext()
                    )}
                  </TableHead>
                );
              })}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableHeader>
        <TableBody>
          {table.getRowModel().rows?.length ? (
            table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
              <TableRow
                key={row.id}
                //data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}
              >
                {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                  <TableCell key={cell.id}>
                    {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
                  </TableCell>
                ))}
              </TableRow>
            ))
          ) : (
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell colSpan={columns.length} className="h-24 text-center">
                No results.
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          )}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Checks;


I believe that the problem is from flexRender , this part of code:
return (
                  <TableHead key={header.id}>
                    {flexRender(
                      header.column.columnDef.header,
                      header.getContext()
                    )}
                  </TableHead>
                );

because i comment it and replace it with "test", and everything  goes well ( table cell content become test ) but idk how to fix it spacialy first time trying shadcn . Thanks in advance!!

I had the same problem and solved it by adding conditional in "columnDef.cell" returning Value if it doesn't exist. I believe it is not the final solution because "getContext" should validate, but it solved the visual problem.
{row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
<TableCell key={cell.id}>
    {cell.column.columnDef.cell ? flexRender(
        cell.column.columnDef.cell,
        cell.getContext()
    ): `${cell.getValue()}`}
</TableCell>))}


Ensure that your accessorKey matches the key in your JSON Data (i.e. mockdata.json).
For example, if you have mockdata.json containing the following:
[
  {
    "Zipcode": 50829,
    "Sub-District": "sub-district 1",
  },
      {
    "Zipcode": 50830,
    "Sub-District": "sub-district 2",
  },
      {
    "Zipcode": 50831,
    "Sub-District": "sub-district 3",
  }
]

then your accessorKey should be exactly Zipcode and not zipcode or ZipCode etc
&
Sub-District and not Sub_district or sub-district etc
